# How to set the settings in DataGrip SQL code style editor so that the join conditions are on separate lines?

Tags: sql, settings, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I need some help configuring SQL editor templates. Now my code after formatting is the following:

```sql
left join table_1 t_1
on a = b and c = 1
```

I want it to be like this:

```sql
left join table_1 t_1
on 
    a = b 
    and c = 1
```

Here is my "Editor -> Code Style -> General settings" window values. I tried some stuff, but it doesn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment DataGrip doesn't support `JOIN` condition formatting.

Please, follow the issue [DBE-17971](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-17971/Format-JOIN-condition)